# Scala Play and IntelliJ support for routes file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, routes

As the title says, I can't figure out how to make IntelliJ support routes file. 
In the image below routes are red-coloured and under ctrl+space there is no prompt with available controllers' methods

How to enable it? I've searched whole google and nothing helped me. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the playframeworksupport plugin?

Comment: @soong yes I have, and what could be also important to mention is that I use typesafe activator to generate my projects and IntelliJ is version 14.1.3. When I create project using activator new or activator ui application, then I often meet problems with importing it to the intelliJ

Comment: That's really odd!  It works for me.  Did you import it as a Play project?

Comment: @soong yes I did, now I do something like: generate project using activator new, then open activator ui and use it to "generate intellij idea files" and then open instead of import project and it works fine but as you see, routes file doesnt work for example..

Comment: @soong maybe we should go on a chat and you would tell me your config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. Here is the bug ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8812

And for now the solution is to add @ before controllers.Application.index

```
GET        /                    @controllers.Application.index
```

And then everything is prompted and works well